# Raspberry Pi operating system based on a high level language such as C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, operating-system, raspberry-pi

I know that operating systems are usually developed in low level languages such as C, C++ or even Assembly. However, is there any way to program a Raspberry Pi operating system in a high level language such as C# or Java?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Comment: They do have a browser, so you can program it in Javascript.

Comment: "I am a very good programmer."

Comment: Both languages compile to an intermediate code which requires a further interpreter to execute it - neither compiles to native code which you would need to write an operating system.

Comment: C/C++ would be a possibility with a cross-compiler : http://hackaday.com/2016/02/03/code-craft-cross-compiling-for-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: The short answer as stated by BWA is no. You need a language that compiles to native binary executable by the CPU. No managed language does that (both C# and Java are managed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I won't say that it's impossible, programming an OS from the ground up in nothing but C#  isn't really feasible. All* the C# compilers (such as the ones for .NET and Mono) compile the C# into an intermediary code called Common Intermediary Language (CIL). This language is interpreted at runtime into bytecode that is then executed by the computer. You can't very well have a runtime interpreting that code if there's no OS to be interpreting it. (Java executes into a Java-esque pseudo-bytecode which is interpreted by the Java Runtime Environment, so the same thing applies.)

What you *can* do is install the [Windows 10 IoT Core OS](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/getstarted) onto your Raspberry Pi. Once you do that, you will be able to program and run C# programs on your machine via UWP. Maybe not a perfect solution for your needs, but it's as close as you can get without writing a custom C# compiler/runtime from scratch.

**: There are one or two third party C# compilers that do compile into C-like bytecode, but AFAIK they are abandoned, highly experimental, support ony  a small subset of the language, or any combination of the three. In addition, using these compilers would disallow you to use any of the .NET standard library, meaning you really will be coding from scratch.*

Comment: C# is possible on Linux with Mono : https://www.maketecheasier.com/write-c-sharp-programs-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Is there also a way to start your C# programm instant? Before you see the bootscreen and the login-screen...?

Comment: @Alwin07 You cannot start a C# program before the OS because the program runs _in_ the OS. That being said, I've never tinkered with Windows 10 IoT myself, so I couldn't say for certain what you can or cannot do. So maybe the OS is streamlined and customizable enough to allow for you to boot directly into a program, bypassing any other boot visuals or other requisites.

Comment: @Abion47 Pity! :(

Comment: @PaulF I generally don't like using Mono unless I need the cross-platform compatibility. Their libraries and C# implementation are outdated compared to .NET, and several components don't always work the way one would expect them to. I'm not trying to bash on Mono, but if I had the option to program in .NET, I'd take it, and Windows 10 IoT allows that. So unless OP wants the flexibility of Linux, I'd still recommend Windows in this case.

Comment: Is there any way to replace the windows boot logo with a animated GIF?

Comment: @Alwin07 I have no idea. Like I said, I've never messed with that OS myself.

Answer (score 2):

At one time, Microsoft Research developed an operating system, [Singularity](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/singularity/), that was primarily written in a variant of C#.  Even for that project though, certain core pieces of the OS had to be written in C and assembly.  While the project predates the Pi, it can give you an idea of what OS components could feasibly be written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Coding a full fledged operating system from the bottom up is obviously difficult and time consuming. What you can do is use any openly available Linux distro or the Linux kernel/source code and modify it in ways you prefer.
To do the same you need to have good hand at C as the source code for Linux is written in C. 
Visit this link I found :

[This is the Linux from scratch page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to programm a os in C#?

Comment: Nope. Never read of anyone having made an OS in C#.

Comment: Possible as a thought experiment or research problem or fun project, but otherwise... :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058876/a-full-operating-system-in-c-sharp